# Selecting a single column from a polars DataFrame giving a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-polars

Does selecting a single column from a polars DataFrame using **`select`** give a DataFrame? If so how to get the series?

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3],
        "B": [6, 7, 8],
        "C": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)
df.select("A")
```

Output

```
A
i64
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, selecting a single column from a polars DataFrame using **`select`** gives a DataFrame

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3],
        "B": [6, 7, 8],
        "C": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)
```

You can check by:

```
df.select("A").shape
#(3, 1)
```

or

```
type(df.select("A"))
#polars.dataframe.frame.DataFrame
```

---

You can get series by:

```
df['A']
```

Checking shape

```
df['A'].shape
#(3,)
```

or

```
df.select("A").to_series()
```

Checking shape

```
df.select("A").to_series().shape
#(3,)
```

or as @jqurious commented

```
df.get_column("A")
```

Comment: [`.get_column()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.get_column.html#polars.DataFrame.get_column)

Comment: Yes, exactly I am adding this to answer.